# Check for waiting notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification

With iOS 5 and the notification center you can have waiting, stacked up notifications each with their own data and message. Is there a way when your program is launched regularly (without tapping on the notification) to discover the waiting notifications and more importantly the data associated with them?

The other question associated with this is when the push notifications come in and your app is in the background does `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` still get called or does it just go and wait till the app is launched and then you're expected to manually handle it with the launch data in the`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

My scenario is that I need to update some core-data models with the data attached to the push notifications so I want those changes reflected no matter how they launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there is no way to find out about notifications other than launching the app directly through them (on iOS 5, that would be right after receiving the notification or from the queued notifications present at the Notification Center).

An alternate strategy would be to use icon badges.

If you badge your app icon when receiving notifications, you could check for that number every time the app is launched and then perform the required actions.

Answer (score 1):

When a notification pops up you can either view it or cancel.  If the user has canceled notification, you can check for them the next time they go in the app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if( localNotif )    {
        // Do some stuff
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;  // Reset num of notifications on app icon
    }
}
```

This method gets fired if you receive a notification while you are in that specific app, or you choose to acknowledge a local notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

BOOL inApp = [application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive;

    if( inApp ) { // they got this in the app
        //Do some stuff in the app
    }
    else {
        // They acknowledged the notification out of the app and here they are
        // Do some other stuff
    }

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

That gives you good coverage for all scenarios with local notifications which would be:

- Notification is received, user cancels.  Check later in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**
- Notification is acknowledged, the app is not open.  Check in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**
- Notification is acknowledged, the app is in the background. **didReceiveLocalNotification:**
- Notification is presented while in the app **didReceiveLocalNotification:**